# Getting error attribute argument must be constant expression

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm using PivateKey in multiple place so I declare it and when I try to call it, a error underlined and say "attribute argument must be constant expression"

I'm newbie, Could anyone help me on this?

```
public class FormController : Controller
{
    public static string reCpatchaPrivateKey = Sitecore.Configuration.Settings.GetSetting("reCaptcha.PrivateKey");

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    [CaptchaValidator(PrivateKey = reCpatchaPrivateKey,
                      ErrorMessage = "Invalid input captcha")]
    public ViewResult ContactUs()
    {
         // .......
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A static string is not a constant.

Try changing

```
public static string reCpatchaPrivateKey = "123456789";
```

to

```
public const string reCpatchaPrivateKey = "123456789";
```

Comment: It works for static value but when I call config setting as below,  it doesn't
`public static string reCpatchaPrivateKey = Sitecore.Configuration.Settings.GetSetting("reCaptcha.PrivateKey");`

Comment: I'm not sure its not work with static value;